# CUBA Platform - How to customize front web app screen?

Tags: java, cuba-platform

I start up my project in CUBA Studio, and click the `/app` link. It comes up with a blank screen:

[image]

There's absolutely nothing in my Screens tab in CUBA Studio.

Is it possible in any way to customize this "homepage" with a GUI screen?

If not, is there a way to have one of the tabs be opened by default, say, open the "Dashboard" tab in Administration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the Screens section in CUBA Studio, and you can click "Create Main Window". There, you can design your layout, and when you go to the app page it'll show right after login.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the screens section in CUBA studio there is a button that says "Create main window". This will create the main window that you can edit in the screen designer.